# No definition for GetLength() in int[][] How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to solve the diagonal difference [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference/problem) but it keeps on giving me this problem:

> Type `int[][]' does not contain a definition for`GetLenght' and no extension method `GetLenght' of type`int[][]' could be found.

```
static int diagonalDifference(int[][] arr) {
    int result = 0;
    int result2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLenght(0); i++)
    {
        result =+ arr[i][i];
    }
    for (int i = arr.GetLength(0); i > 0; i--) {
        result2 =+ arr[i][i];
    }
    return Math.Abs(result+result2);
}
```

This are my references:

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using static System.Array;
using System;
```

Comment: You have a typo, it's `GetLength()` not `GetLenght()`

Comment: can we close it as typographical mistake ?=! @steve16351 gave already the correct answer

Comment: Maybe read the error message a bit more closely next time?

Comment: You should also be carefully its `+=` and not `=+`

Comment: I changed the code a lot also I had to do

    *for (int i = arr.Length **- 1**; i > 0; i--)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try `.Length` since it's not really a two dimensional array.

**Edit:**

You should check `if(arr.Length == arr[0].Length)` Because you might get an OutOfBoundException if the arrays do not have equal length.

**Edit 2:**

You can make a single loop to do the job:

```
static int DiagonalDifference(int[][] arr)
{
    if(arr.Length != arr[0].Length)
        throw new ArgumentException("Sides do not have equal length.");
    int result = 0;
    int result2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        result += arr[i][i];
        result2 += arr[arr.Length - i - 1][arr.Length - i - 1];
    }
    return Math.Abs(result + result2);
}
```

Comment: It is a 2 dimensional array

Comment: yes but 'real' 2 dimensional arrays in C# can be done like this: `int[,] twoDimArray;`

Comment: @Axel have added an example how you can make this run with just one loop, feel free to check this out.

Answer (score 0):

GetLenght?? Maybe GetLength. I hope this helps. If not, try to specify argument 1 or 0, ..